# Doing Query "In" options in a cloud NoSQL Type Database

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Background:
We are currently storing our files on AWS S3(mainly images). On our client application, need to upload a batch of files to s3 together(500+ files), and before uploading a file, we always check if these files exists in S3 by pinging S3 with file id and see if header exist or not one by one(assuming there is not other ways to check if a file exists on the client side). This is obviously a performance kill on the client application.

Our attempts:
On AWS we created a indexing table stored on DynamoDB(A Cloud DB) which keeps tracks all the file names(assuming file name is unique for each files) that has currently existing S3 bucket(for example, use lambda to insert and delete record on file insertion and deletion). What we want to do is that before uploading files from the client we want to run a query/scan against the cloud database and to check if a list of file names exist in the tracked records. NOTICE: It is very important that we DON'T want to check the file name existence one by one since it will not improve much comparing to our existing solution. We want to check a list of file names if they exist in the database. (Like doing a dif between two file name lists)

Challenges:
For NoSQL database it is not possible to do a query records with in a list.

I want to gain some more ideas on how to achieve want we want to do.

There are some options that we are currently thinking of:
1. instead to using NoSQL database we use a relational database so that we can do table joint or query file name in a list
2. Instead of keeping a list of filenames on NoSql DB, we keep a hashed results on different cells and retrieved the hashed result to client set and the client will do the list comparison then.

Answer (score 0):

My english is not good and My understanding is:
You want check a list of file names if they exist and file name is db hashkey.

You can use batchLoad to get the results.But be careful,the batckLoad api have count limit。

Answer (score 0):

If your DynamoDB table size is small, you can do a Scan operation and set the filter expression for filename with ["IN" operator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html#ConditionExpressionReference)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using Elasticache as well to make your solution more scalable instead of hitting DynamoDB for every request. And, you can have 2 lambda functions, one to update DynamoDB when there is an update to the S3 bucket, and another one update the Elasticache with the DynamoDB updates based on DynamoDB streams. Once cache is updated, subsequent lookups before S3 would find the latest updates. A few points to keep in mind in this approach are - asynchronous updates and eventual consistency. So, you might have to see how your client has to handle it.